# Wifi Signal and Disconnecting Problem in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I have a Dell Inspiron 3567 With Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter i have to sit too close near by access point to connect with it and i did not get proper signal in my laptop it will disconnected frequently I have search in forum but i get solution for realtech not for qualcomm.

Here is my Wireless card Log of System: [Log is Here](https://pastebin.com/MeUFPx8v)

Comment: Ive try it but not work for my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal enter `gedit admin:///etc/default/grub`
Once the file is opened go to the line that has "quiet splash" and add `pcie_aspm=off` inside the quotes so

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

becomes

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"
```

save and exit gedit and do `sudo update-grub` then reboot

Comment: It is not very clear what does "add inside the quotes. I suggest giving an example.

Comment: I had to get on a laptop that still has grub installed, been using systemd boot

Comment: Is it `pcie_aspm=off:`, `pcie_aspm=off`, or `pcie_aspm=off,`?

Comment: Just `pcie_aspm=off` @pilot6 must have been an issue with the edit and copy/paste

Comment: It's not work I've try it